# LDAP Search in multiple organisations

Tags: ldap

I try to make a search in multiple organisations inside the LDAP. At the end I want to get a list of all LDAP Users inside my organisations.

My search string should be include something like this

```
o=Company1,o=Company2
```

How is it possible to search in multiple oganisations?

Answer (score 0):

With LDAP, you search from a single base DN.

If your organisations are under a common base, then you can search through all of them, and you use the LDAP Filter to refine what you are searching for.

If they are not under a common base, then you cannot search with a single LDAP request, unless you introduce a Directory Proxy Server to do the aggregation for you.